# c++ : can't access elements in const string&

Tags: c++

`word[0]` returns the entire string instead of the first element.

How do I access elements in a `const string& word` that I obtain from a function.

```
void something(const string& word)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
     cout << word[i];
}
```

Is there a way to convert it into a string??

Please help!!

Comment: This needs some code so that we can see what word[0] is actually referring to.

Comment: Done, It's simply a string passed to a function by reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my code. That has nothing to do with reading elements in cstring&

Answer (score 2):

Works correctly in my system, no problem. Here's sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void myfunc(const std::string& word){

  std::cout << word[0] << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
   myfunc("test");

}
```

Output:

```
~$ ./a.out
t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert from const string into string, just copy it.

```
std::string new_word = word;
std::cout << new_word;
```